# hudson / jenkins - Showing content when clicking a result link

Tags: html, junit, hudson, jenkins, publish

I have job that runs an executable which yields a JUnit report.
This report is parsed by Hudson (the 'Publish JUnit test result report' option is checked),
and each testcase is shown as a link.
What I would like to do is to show an HTML page, when a user clicks a link.

For example, this is the JUnit report that Hudson parses

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuite name="Root" package="RunnerRoot" errors="0" failures="3" tests="5" time="20.2">
  <testcase classname="Runner" name="Test1" time="3.2283228" />
  <testcase classname="Runner" name="Test2" time="2.9512951">
   <failure> Error Running the test </failure>
  </testcase>
```

Hudson creates two links called Test1 and Test2, and I want to show 
a customized content from an HTML file upon clicking a link.

Thank you

Comment: You kind already have that link structure in the Test Result page... or do you want to have more control over how that page is displayed ?

Comment: Hi,sorry for the late response. As for now, if the I click the link in the Test Result page, I get a page that shows me the stack trace of the test case (i.e, the failure message). I want to show an html content instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is no way to alter the Test Results page, although you might be able to achieve this by writing a plugin. However, there is a plugin that allows you to publish your own html report for a job - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin. This will appear as a link in the left panel rather than replace the Test Result page, but it is probably the closest to what you want.